# Android wear: LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH and LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM

Tags: android, speech-recognition, wear-os

What is difference between `LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH` and `LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM`? Why is it required for Intent which is used for input speech?

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to inform the receiver of the intent (i.e. the speech recognizer) what type of language the user is likely to speak, e.g. "web search terms" or something more free form. The name of the calling app is typically also available to the receiver (e.g. was it Maps or YouTube), and is likely to be used by the recognizer to fine tune the results, and is likely to have more effect on the results than the choice of the language model extra.